# pyautogui not working in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, python-idle, pyautogui

i have download pyautogui through pip and pip3 and up to date.
no error pop out when executing .py code, but no respond (the mouse is not moving as expected) is given out.

i am testing with the code:

```
from time import sleep
import pyautogui as pt

sleep(2)
pt.moveTo(200,200,duration = 1)
```

however when i run the code in IDLE the mouse can move.
i am thinking will it be the py file save on desktop (not same directory as the pyautogui library), or different directory of pyautogui and python3...

my set up is macos bigsur v 11.6
and python v 3.9.7 64-bit

here are the location of pyautogui

```
xxx@xxx-MacBook-Pro auto_ig % pip show pyautogui
Name: PyAutoGUI
Version: 0.9.53
Summary: PyAutoGUI lets Python control the mouse and keyboard, and other GUI automation tasks. For Windows, macOS, and Linux, on Python 3 and 2.
Home-page: https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui
Author: Al Sweigart
Author-email: al@inventwithpython.com
License: BSD
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: pymsgbox, PyTweening, pyscreeze, pygetwindow, mouseinfo, pyobjc-core, pyobjc
Required-by:
```

and here are the python[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15yU7.png)

and i have tried run on terminal and it mention no-module can be found...

just feeling so confused and frustrate for try to solving this for days, can somebody help.......

Comment: Please copy-and-paste the messages you see and the terminal command you used to run it there. I can imagine that pyautogui might have a conflict with VS that is does not have with IDLE.  But that should not be the case with running in the terminal/

Comment: Can you check which python environment you are using with `print(sys.executable)`? In the `IDLE `, `VSCode` and `terminal`.

Comment: And please provide more information when you ask the question. don't be shame of share the info. If you want provide a screenshot, please provide a bigger one, from this picture you have provided we can't get too much information. And the terminal information you provided, you have conceal too much information, if you want someone others can provide some help, please share your information, and willn't anyone through your information go get anything from you. Thanks, and have a good day.